# GCM Service with WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

In my comprehension, GCMBaseIntentService fully provides methods for listening messages from GCM and also handling long running tasks (registering registration id with our demo server).
Is that true?
If true, 
- Why don't we use a normal BroadcastReceiver to listen messages from GCM?
- In some examples, a WakefulBroadcastReceiver is frequently used to start a IntentSevice which also gets messages from GCM and handles them, why do we use this?
Please help me to understand this !
Any ideas would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

A WakefulBroadcastReceiver is used for GCM to ensure the device does not go to sleep before the app handles the message. The general flow is:

1. GCM library gets the message, sends a broadcast to your app, and holds a wake lock while your broadcast receiver is running.
2. Your WakefulBroadcastReceiver receives the message intent, then calling startWakefulService takes a wakelock for a while to ensure the device doesn't go to sleep before the Service starts.
3. Service starts and processed the message, it should also take its own wakelock if it plans to do some processing that needs to happen now, and takes some time

If you use an ordinary BroadcastReceiver and don't take a wake lock, then the device could go to sleep between 2 and 3, meaning the message may appear to get delayed.